# How can I display words in a foreign language on an English website?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

**What I want**

Hi, I am building an English website as a hobby about Japanese shrines. The website will need to explain some Japanese words, which will be presented in Japanese.

**What I tried**

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Hello, this is some text</p>
    <p>御朱印</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This displays fine on my computer, but when it goes live the Japanese word becomes "€€â€•ã€€å¾¡æœ±å°". I tried Googling for help, however I keep coming across things that are not relevant to me.

**What I want**

How can someone choose to use words such as this on an English website? Presumably Mandarin will be the same, Russian too etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display Japanese characters you need to display data in UTF-8 format. If you are developing your website in php use the method [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Comment: Great, that gave me enough information to know where I need to look and do some more research. Problem solved.